# How to get the error causing rows in try and except using python?

Tags: python, datetime, try-except

I am new to python. I am looking for a way to get the error causing rows into a new data frame. So, I have a data frame from where I want to check if a date column is in a particular date format or not. Though I have written the code and getting the output correct, I want to get the error causing rows into a new data frame. How do I do it?

My code:

```
df =

   Date         cars
0  2020-01-02   two
1  01-02-2020   three
3  01022020     four
4  080920201    five
```

```
import dateutil.parser 

for row in df.Date:
    try:
        valid = dateutil.parser.parse(row)
        print(valid)
    except ValueError:
        invaild = "error caused row"
        print(invalid)
```

Execpted output:

```
    valid
    0  2020-01-02  00:00:00
    1  2020-01-02  00:00:00
    3  2020-01-02  00:00:00
 Invaild

4  080920201    five
```

Comment: You already got it, it's called `row`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 how do I call it?

Comment: You can for example print it: `print(row)`

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am getting all the rows. I need only the rows which are causing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print something different, depending on whether a row was valid, print it either in the *try clause* or in the *except clause*:

```
for row in df.Date:
    try:
        valid = dateutil.parser.parse(row)
        print(row, "was a valid row")
    except ValueError:
        print(row, "caused an error")
```

Or to collect all rows causing an error in a list, call the list `append` method inside the except clause:

```
invalid_rows = []
for row in df.Date:
    try:
        valid = dateutil.parser.parse(row)
    except ValueError:
        invalid_rows.append(row)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions:

> The try statement works as follows.
>
> - First, the *try clause* (the statement(s) between the `try` and `except` keywords) is executed.
> - If no exception occurs, the *except clause* is skipped and execution of the `try` statement is finished.
> - If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the rest of the clause is skipped. Then if its type matches the exception named
>   after the `except` keyword, the except clause is executed, and then
>   execution continues after the `try` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I clearly understood this :) You helped aloot :)